# Moving worksheet to new workbook is slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have a fairly long macro. The last step is to move five new sheets to a new workbook. This is taking several minutes.

I've isolated this part.

```vb
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim TempSheets As Variant

TempSheets = Array(Sheets to be moved...)

Sheets(TempSheets).Move

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

It speeds up to take only 10 or so seconds when I turn off screen updating. But the new worksheet is nowhere to be found.

As an alternative idea, I tried naming a new worksheet first:

```vb
Dim newwb As Workbook

Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
```

But couldn't get the syntax right for moving the sheets to that new workbook without saving and giving it a name first. I tried:

```vb
Sheets(TempSheets).Move Before:=newwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

I could create a new workbook that would be visible with screen updating turned off using that `Set newwb = Workbooks.add`.

Comment: Are you sure it is taking several minutes for that? Can you put `Msgbox now` before and after `Sheets(TempSheets).Move` and see what is the exact time difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim NewWb As Workbook
Set NewWb = Application.Workbooks.Add

Dim TempSheets As Variant
TempSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim StartTmr As Double  'this is just to measure the time it needs
StartTmr = Timer

'move the sheets before the first sheet in the new workbook
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TempSheets).Move Before:=NewWb.Sheets(1)

Debug.Print "After Move: ", Timer - StartTmr  'time needed for moving

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Debug.Print "After Calc: ", Timer - StartTmr  'time needed for moving and calculating
```

This perfectly works for me and within milliseconds. Check it out and check if the long time it takes is really the moving code or turning the calculation on again. check the output in the immediate window, it should be something like:

```
After Move:    0,265625 
After Calc:    0,296875
```

Comment: Thanks PEH — worked great. The key is creating that new book first and then moving sheets to it. (Clearly there's an issue with moving to a new unnamed book with screen updating off.) For fun, I ran your timer (don't laugh, working from home on an older machine). Here's what I got.

Your code: 1.14 
My code using Sheets(TempSheets).Move instead of creating a new book first: 5.13 (but with screen updating  off — can't find the new sheet!) 
My code with screen updating turned on: (wait for it): 186.679

I'm going to grab a beer and toast you with my extra three minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a similar problem, I worked around it by

declaring the original workbook and the new one with concrete names, e.g. wbOrig and wbNew
2. saving the original workbook under the new one's name by using the `.SaveAs` method
3. setting the wbNew to be the copy just made
4. if necessary, deleting sheets not needed

```
Dim wbOrig As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim strPath As String 'the path to your new wb
Dim strFileName As String  ' the name of your new wb

Set wbOrig = Workbooks("YourWorkbooksName.xlsm")
 wbOrig.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Set wbNew = Workbooks(strFileName)
' if necessary, you can delete all sheets you do not need here now
```

Maybe not the most elegant way, but effective and certainly taking less than 10 minutes to complete.